# What is the difference between feeds served by my WordPress install vs feeds served by FeedBurner?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, customization, feed, feedburner

What is the difference between feeds served by my WordPress install vs feeds served by FeedBurner?

How to disable hosted Wiordpress feed completely and use feedburner?

Comment: I'm tempted to close as subjective / argumentative. The only part of this question that's worth attention is the fourth question. All three of the other questions are subjective.

Comment: Worded somewhat improperly, but I don't think it's subjective.  The OP doesn't have a clear understanding of what the "features" of RSS feeds are.  Perhaps a better question is "What is the difference between feeds served by my WordPress install vs feeds served by FeedBurner?"

Comment: @gabrielk I agree that that would be a much better question. But the question, as it is currently worded, is subjective. You'll also notice that neither I nor anyone else has actually voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some reasons I think FB does well:

- feed statistics: subscribers, item view and clicks
- email subscription: control email template, subscribers
- sharing posts on social networks with FeedFlare
- monitize with Google Adsense
- reduces CPU usage on your host.

Some of above features you can do with plugins, but it costs CPU usage and sometimes host space. With FB, you let FB do all of these stuff without any prices.

FB has its own plugin that redirects WP feed to FB automatically, you can find it in FB.

Answer (score 2):

FeedBurner provides stats that WordPress does not, such as analytics. Here are some uses of FeedBurner features:

http://www.wisnet.com/noteworthy/7-useful-feedburner-features-for-bloggers/0/0/418/

Out-of-the-box, WordPress feeds work fine and do just what they're supposed to do.

Comment: OK Thanks. Please reply to my second question also